# Accessing OleVariant containing VT_ARRAY of VT_RECORD from Delphi

Tags: delphi

Using Delphi, I need to access a OleVariant containing one or more records in an array.

The method I call returns a VT_ARRAY of VT_RECORD, and the records themselves are defined as:

```
struct StreamTimeInfo {
  unsigned int PID;
  LONGLONG PTS;
  LONGLONG TimeStamp;
};
```

My code is like this:

```
procedure Test;
type
  TStreamInfo = record
    PID: Cardinal;
    PTS: Int64;
    TimeStamp: Int64;  
  end;
var
  Value: OleVariant
  StreamTime: TStreamInfo;
begin
  GetValue(Value); // Value holds a VT_ARRAY of VT_RECORD

  // How should I access the array of records in Delphi?
  // I've tried this to get to the first element:
  StreamTime := TStreamInfo(TVarData(Value).VPointer^);
end;
```

I do not understand how to access the records from Delphi.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried both packed/non packed record, no difference. Also, the code is 32-bit (Delphi and the DLL I am calling).

Comment: The original code does not use #pragma pack 1 so I've removed the packed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never done this before, but I think this should work.

```
type 
  TStreamInfoArray = array [0..MaxArrayCount-1] of TStreamInfo; 
  PStreamInfoArray = ^TStreamInfoArray; 
var 
  Value: Variant;
  p: PStreamInfoArray;
  StreamInfo: TStreamInfo;
begin 
  GetValue(Value);
  p := PStreamInfoArray(VarArrayLock(Value)); 
  try
    StreamInfo := p^[Index]; 
  finally
    VarArrayUnlock(Value); 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: David, Amazing! Your code is working just perfectly. I am a little embarrased that I didn't figure this one out myself. Thank you!

Comment: I'm just as amazed as you are! Actually the packing issue matters on 32 bit too doesn't it. The record has padding after `PID`.

Comment: I'd like to update this question with my final code for future reference and as a reference for others. Should I edit the existing post or add an answer myself? What is the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference and for others, here is the final working code:

```
// Original C-Source definition of StreamTimeInfo
// import "oaidl.idl";
// import "ocidl.idl";
// [uuid(A5AA2ACD-BEA0-4570-9232-D8301A6DAE0F)] 
// struct StreamTimeInfo {
//   unsigned int    PID;       
//   LONGLONG        PTS;       
//   LONGLONG        TimeStamp; 
// };
// cpp_quote("typedef struct StreamTimeInfo StreamTimeInfo;")

procedure GetStreamTimes;
type
  TStreamTimeInfo = record
    PID: Cardinal;
    PTS: Int64;
    TimeStamp: Int64;
  end;
  TStreamTimeInfoArray = array[0..31] of TStreamTimeInfo;
  PStreamTimeInfoArray = ^TStreamTimeInfoArray;
var
  Value: OleVariant;
  SizeOfArray: Integer;
  PtrToArray: PStreamTimeInfoArray;
begin
  GetValue(EMPGPDMX_STREAMTIMES, Value);
  if VarArrayDimCount(Value) = 1 then
  begin
    SizeOfArray := 1 + VarArrayHighBound(Value, 1) - VarArrayLowBound(Value, 1);
    PtrToArray := PStreamTimeInfoArray(VarArrayLock(Value));
    try
     for I := 0 to SizeOfArray - 1 do
     begin
       StreamTimeInfo := PtrToArray^[I];
       // Usage Sample:
       // FStatus.StreamTimePID[I] := StreamTimeInfo.PID;
       // FStatus.StreamTimePTS[I] := StreamTimeInfo.PTS;
       // FStatus.StreamTimeTS[I] := StreamTimeInfo.TimeStamp;
     end;
   finally
     VarArrayUnlock(Value);
   end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Well, this is actually wrong. You don't want to use `VarArrayDimCount` that way. `VarArrayDimCount` returns the number of dimensions. So, `0` if it's not an array, `1` if it is a 1D array, `2` for a 2D array, say a matrix. You want to check that `VarArrayDimCount` returns `1`. And then use `1+VarArrayHighBound(Value, 1)-VarArrayLowBound(Value, 1)` to find the number of elements.

Comment: Doh! You are absolutely right. I've updated the code. No need to test VarArrayDimCount as I am already testing with VarIsArray and the GetValue() call will never return a multidimensional array. Thanks!

Comment: I think I'd convert `VarIsArray` to `VarArrayDimCount(...)=1` to assert that you have not got a multi-dim array. Anyway, I guess is was valuable for you to post this answer!

Comment: One final comment. If you have range checking on, you'll get runtime errors if there are more than 32 elements in the array. In which case you can use a very large upper index on the array type. Or not bother with the array type and use pointer arithmetic, e.g. `inc(p)`. If you don't have range checking on, you can make the array be `[0..0]`!