# Send Delphi record in PSafeArray

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to use an ActiveX object in a Delphi application. One of the methods that I must use require that I send the following structure:

```
SCategoryMember = packed record
    terminal: WideString;
    semanticStatements: WideString;
    symbolAttributeDefinitions: WideString;
end;
```

through this method call:

```
procedure SetCategoryMembers(var a_category: SGrammarSymbol; 
  a_mode: SetCategoryMode;  
  var a_members: PSafeArray); safecall;
```

where the `SCategoryMember` structure should be sent as an element in the `a_members` parameter.

Any idea on how I can convert the packet record into an element in a `PSafeArray`?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6347140/62576) for a link that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you expect an array of records to be sent to the ActiveX method.

AFAIK, Delphi does not support direct marshaling of COM record types (i.e. the internal `VT_RECORD` type). But you can try to [create a safe array pointing to the data](http://blog.virtec.org/2008/07/the-mysteries-of-psafearray/). But the fact that your structure has `WideString` members may be an additional problem. It is somewhat difficult, but [feasible, if you take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16297637/458259).

What we usually do with COM for such structures is to define an object instead of a record (e.g. a `class` instead of a `struct` in C#). And insteas of an array, we define a `List<>`. Then it is imported as Delphi interfaces in the corresponding `..._tlb.pas` with all needed members. No need to tweak with the COM internals. If you can change the ActiveX code, I recommend you go this way.

Comment: Why some anonymous down-voting?